# R return to a previous point in a function if some statements are not met

Tags: r, if-statement

I have this sample code

```
sq <- function(){
  d <- readline("give number(0 to 10): ")

  if (as.numeric(d) <= 5){
    dsquare <- as.numeric(d) ^ 2
    return(dsquare)
  } else {
    stop("OK")
  }

}
```

I want, instead of stopping the function, to get back to the point that the user was providing the d with the `readline()` function. Is there a way to do it easily?

Comment: Try `Recall` or just calling the function again by name?

Comment: I am trying to find an example of recall(). Otherway, you mean after else to call again the code from d<-...to where the if finishes?

Comment: Recall might be ok for small functions. But if I do not want to start the function from the begining? Is there a way to Recall() a part of a function? Or maybe should I break my function to smaller and recall from the point I want to start again?

Comment: Perhaps `tryCatch` outside `sq`, catching the error from `stop`.

Comment: I am dissapointed. I tried to separate the d<-... as a function of its own. but I cannot have an answer. I get errors or just nothing...I cannot figure how to call a function within a function...

Answer (score 2):

Echoing Thomas's comment, perhaps you can just do something like this:

```
sq<-function(){
  d<-readline("give number(0 to 5): ")

  if (as.numeric(d)<=5){
    dsquare<-(as.numeric(d)^2)
    return(dsquare)
  }
  else{
    Message <- paste("Input should be less than or equal to 5.", 
                     "Please enter a new value (0 to 5)", sep = "\n")
    message(Message, appendLF=TRUE)
    sq()
  } 
}
```

Here's a trial of a few numbers:

```
sq()
# give number(0 to 5): 1.5
# [1] 2.25
sq()
# give number(0 to 5): 6
# Input should be less than or equal to 5.
# Please enter a new value (0 to 5)
# give number(0 to 5): 7
# Input should be less than or equal to 5.
# Please enter a new value (0 to 5)
# give number(0 to 5): 6
# Input should be less than or equal to 5.
# Please enter a new value (0 to 5)
# give number(0 to 5): 2
# # [1] 4
```

Comment: This is an answer but what if I want to separate the d() as an independent function, then call it in the first line of the sq() function, and when I am to the point of else, then the d() function would be called again, and start from this point?

Comment: Iteration seems more appropriate than recursion here

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer due to your answers too and thank you for this.

First I do a function called d() which is:

```
d<-function(){
  dd<-readline("give number(0 to 10): ")

if (as.numeric(dd)<=5){
  dsquare<-(as.numeric(dd)^2)
  return(dsquare)
} else{
  d()
}

}
```

then I call this function in the sq() function which is like these 3 lines:

```
sq<-function(){
  d()
}
```

of course the script I want to apply is not that simple, but i'll figure it out!!
Generally, I understood that you must separate the function in many smaller ones, and in you call when you want the function which is where at the point you want to begin again.

EDIT: if I want to call a variable from d() to sq(), how can I do this?
I tried to put the return(dsquare) in the sq() function instead of the d() but it gives ERROR.

Comment: `sq <- d` does the same thing as your last code block but I really don't see the point of it.

Comment: It'a a general form, not the code I want to apply this question I did.

Comment: Store the return value into a variable...  If you want to use an value that isn't returned from d() then no you can't do that.

Comment: I didn't understand you. 
The dsquare is from d() but as I call d() in sq() I ask the dsquare to be returned from sq(). Perhaps an example would make it clearer for me. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I did it. For now it works. I assigned the variables in the nested function as global with <<- It worked but I am not sure if it's the best way!